# How to keep partition columns when reading in ORC files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

When reading in an ORC file in Spark, if you specify the partition column in the path, that column will not be included in the dataset. For example, if we have

```
val dfWithColumn = spark.read.orc("/some/path") 

val dfWithoutColumn = spark.read.orc("/some/path/region_partition=1")
```

then dfWithColumn will have a region_partition column, but dfWithoutColumn will not. How can I specify that I want to include all columns, even if they're partitioned?

I am using spark 2.2 on scala.

EDIT: This is a re-usable Spark program that will take in its arguments from the command line; I want the program to work even if the user passes in a specific partition of a table instead of the whole table. So, using Dataset.filter is not an option.

Comment: If the intention of the second line was to only get data of that partition, Why did you not filter the DF with the column information? Since DFs are lazily evaluated, the predicate would get pushed down and there is no overhead of reading the whole file

Comment: I interpreted question differently to tgecanswers

Answer (score 4):

It is same as parquet.

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery

```
df = spark.read.option("basePath", "file://foo/bar/")
         .orc("file://foo/bar/partition_column=XXX")
```

df has a 'partition_column' column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your partitioned columns in the path, add them as filters. Modify your code to -

```
val dfWithColumn = spark.read.orc("/some/path/").where($"region_partition" === 1)
```

This will identify the schema properly and will read data only for "region_partition=1" directory.

Comment: See my edit; I don't want to only read in a certain partition, I want my program to work even if the user passes in a certain partition instead of the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to load one partition not the whole data, then you can get benefit of the lazy loading of spark and do the following:

```
val dfWithColumn = spark.read.orc("/some/path") 
dfWithColumn= dfWithColumn.where($"region_partition" === 1)
```

By doing this you will be getting data from the folder:

> "/some/path/region_partition=1"

The win of this is that you keep the original structure with having the partition column inside your dataset.

But if you aim to manipulate the read dataset to add some column with some value I suggest to use the method:

> withColumn

Comment: See my edit; I don't want to only read in a certain partition, I want my program to work even if the user passes in a certain partition instead of the whole table.